# missing python3-distutils for python3.8 ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, python3

So I install python 3.8:

```
justin@justin-Precision-5550:/usr/lib$ sudo aptitude install python3.8
[sudo] password for justin: 
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libpython3.8-minimal{a} libpython3.8-stdlib{a} python3.8 
  python3.8-minimal{a} 
0 packages upgraded, 4 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
Need to get 0 B/4,550 kB of archives. After unpacking 18.5 MB will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n/?] y
(Reading database ... 164546 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libpython3.8-minimal_3.8.0-3~18.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpython3.8-minimal:amd64 (3.8.0-3~18.04.1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../python3.8-minimal_3.8.0-3~18.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python3.8-minimal (3.8.0-3~18.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libpython3.8-stdlib:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libpython3.8-stdlib_3.8.0-3~18.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpython3.8-stdlib:amd64 (3.8.0-3~18.04.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python3.8.
Preparing to unpack .../python3.8_3.8.0-3~18.04.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking python3.8 (3.8.0-3~18.04.1) ...
Setting up libpython3.8-minimal:amd64 (3.8.0-3~18.04.1) ...
Setting up python3.8-minimal (3.8.0-3~18.04.1) ...
Setting up libpython3.8-stdlib:amd64 (3.8.0-3~18.04.1) ...
Setting up python3.8 (3.8.0-3~18.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-11ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-1ubuntu3.18.04.2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
```

then I install python3-distutils

```
justin@justin-Precision-5550:/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils$ sudo aptitude install python3-distutils
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  python3-distutils python3-lib2to3{a} 
0 packages upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
Need to get 0 B/217 kB of archives. After unpacking 2,118 kB will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n/?] y
Selecting previously unselected package python3-lib2to3.
(Reading database ... 165195 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../python3-lib2to3_3.6.5-3_all.deb ...
Unpacking python3-lib2to3 (3.6.5-3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package python3-distutils.
Preparing to unpack .../python3-distutils_3.6.5-3_all.deb ...
Unpacking python3-distutils (3.6.5-3) ...
Setting up python3-lib2to3 (3.6.5-3) ...
Setting up python3-distutils (3.6.5-3) ...
```

However when I check the source files version python3.8 doesn't appear to have distlib installed?

```
justin@justin-Precision-5550:/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils$ pwd
/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils
justin@justin-Precision-5550:/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils$ ll
total 40
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 Aug 13 16:17 ./
drwxr-xr-x 28 root root 12288 Aug 13 16:17 ../
-rw-r--r--  1 root root   236 Feb 26 09:10 __init__.py
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root  4096 Aug 13 16:17 __pycache__/
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 12345 Feb 26 09:10 version.py
```

This is causing issues when I try and setup virtual envs in intelliJ:

[image]

I'm not sure if im missing a step here or something is broken? I tried searching for a specific distutils.util for python3.8 but found none

Comment: `/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/util.py` seems to be included https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic-updates/all/python3-distutils/filelist ........ Are you sure the right python version is used in your " setup command" ?

Comment: Sorry Knud im not sure what you mean? Like the command IntelliJ runs or?

Answer (score 0):

ok so I stupidly disabled "Recommended updates"

[image]

which meant that I could not get the correct package version for python3-disutils. After enabling this and then upgrading to the latest version the files are now there.